# Do Lure Modules Stack?

Tags: pokemon-go

Can multiple people put a Lure Module on the same PokeStop at the same time, and does it increase the amount of Pokemon that appear?

Answer (score 10):

You may not place multiple Modules (even of different types!) on a Pokestop as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can only place one lure module per pokestop. However if you are in an area with several [pokestops](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Pokestops) in close proximity then you can place one on each to increase the local pokemon spawn rate.