# Is it beneficial to layer lures on overlapping pokestops?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have two pokestops accessible from my desk at work, close enough together that when both of them have lures the zones of influence overlap.

Is it beneficial to put down lures on both of these stops at the same time? Will the overlapping area have an even greater chance of spawning pokemon, or will it just be wasting resources on a larger area with the same chances of spawning?

Comment: If your radar ring covers both fully, then there is no use to put down lure on both. I don't think the overlapping would have any impact on spawning. The only benefit I see is two spawns simultaneously.

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate! For some reason that question didn't show up in the similar questions list when I was initially posting.

Comment: Where do you work and how can I take your job? Or at least your desk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is beneficial as being in the area of multiple lures increases the rate of which you find pokemon. Some of the places where there are 3 pokestops in the same area are called triple lure setups as there are usually 3 lures running simultaneously.

Do get some work done though =)

Comment: Do you have a source that says this is actually beneficial?

Comment: Both of the following links' answers say that multiple lures increase pokemon spawning rates http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/274346/158596 http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273459/do-lure-modules-on-multiple-pokestops-in-your-radius-stack . I am unsure which websites are considered as verified sources as (there are multiple reddit threads and a forbes.com article) I found but am unsure if these are considered as trusted sources.

Comment: That's for the local area.  This is asking about the *overlapping* area between the pokestops.  Lures increase the spawning for their own areas, yes.  That's what they're supposed to do.  But do overlapping areas see greater spawn rates?

Comment: Doesn't the first answer from the second link answer that?
"yes

We just tested this. The spawn rate for 1 vs 2 vs 3 had obvious increases. Although due to natural variations, we couldn't tell for sure if it was a linear increase or not, but it looked like each stop had its own increased arrival rate of Pokemon."